# INDEX MATCH on structured references / #value error

Tags: excel, office365

The use of INDEX / MATCH on 2 defined tables and a structured reference on their columns causes a #value error, although the function has been entered as an array-function.

Given:

```
**Table1:**  
Key1|SourceVal  
1|A  
2|AA

**Table2:**  
Key2|ValDisp  
1|_{=INDEX(Table1;MATCH(Table2[@[Key2]];Table1[Key1];0);Table1[SourceVal])}_
```

The formula entered in column "ValDisp" effects in a #value error.
The formula analyzer shows, that the correct value is found, but is turned into #value during the last step.

Comment: If you're trying to return a value from Source Val, your formula would be: `=INDEX(Table1[SourceVal]);MATCH(Table2[@[Key2]];Table1[Key1];0))` and it doesn't need array-entry.

Comment: @Rory thanks, but clip match is outside of the index clips, which wont work. So you mean to define return matrix as the column i want to return?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'clip' but that is the formula to return a value from SourceVal where key2 is found in the key1 column of Table1. If the formula is in Table2, you don't need the Table2 reference.

Comment: Essentially you don't need to index the entire table if you are only interested in results from one column - you can find the result in that column as the Match will find the row number for you regardless of the column being in the INDEX... If you are indexing the entire table, you would then need to use a second MATCH on the title column to find the column you want returned as an integer... that or don't give that parameter and just use the first column

Comment: @Rory and @Glitch_Doctor are right. Essentially you are feeding the `INDEX()` formula a string value where it would expect an integer returning your `#VALUE` error.

Comment: clip = parenthesis (translation issue) - your formula has 2x(( and 3x)))
In your INDEX formula is closed by an ) ==> missing arguments

Comment: `=INDEX(Table1[SourceVal];MATCH([@Key2];Table1[Key1];0))` is what he meant I'm sure.

Comment: Wow it works and your're right (overlooking the ")" )! Thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INDEX can be invoked in two ways. In the way you are using it, first parameter is a range, and second and third parameters are numbers.

You are using `=INDEX(Table1;MATCH(Table2[@[Key2]];Table1[Key1];0);Table1[SourceVal])`

Last parameter `Table1[SourceVal]` **does not** return a number, so try to replace it with column number:

`=INDEX(Table1;MATCH(Table2[@[Key2]];Table1[Key1];0);2)`

[image]

Another option would be using a second MATCH that searchs for the name of the column and returns its position inside headers area of `Table1`. Something like this:

> *I got Excel 2007 so my structured references are different. Not @ like in Excel 2010 and higher*

You could replace the `2` by `MATCH(Table1[[#HEADERS];[Sourceval]];Table1[#HEADERS];0)`